# registering and unregistering broadcast receivers?

Tags: android

> if you register a receiver in onCreate(Bundle) using the activity's
>   context, you should unregister it in onDestroy() to prevent leaking
>   the receiver out of the activity context. If you register a receiver
>   in onResume(), you should unregister it in onPause() to prevent
>   registering it multiple times (If you don't want to receive broadcasts
>   when paused, and this can cut down on unnecessary system overhead).

I got this from the official documentation. Why we say "if we register a receiver in onCreate(), we should unregister it in onDestroy()"?

Comment: My question is not when to register and unregister a Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: that link or similar links has already has answers for this question . See `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: You should register and unregister your receivers onStart() and onStop().

The only reason an Activity would register BroadcastReceivers is to use the events in some way on the current activity, to inform the User of an event. If onStop() has been called, then the Activity is no longer in the foreground, and therefore cant update the User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - if you register a receiver in onCreate(Bundle) using the
>   activity's context, you should unregister it in onDestroy() to prevent
>   leaking the receiver out of the activity context

`onCreate()` of an `Activity` is called when the `Activity` is created for the first time and `onDestry()` of an `Activity` is called when that `Activity` is destroyed. Both functions are called only once in lifetime of an `Activity`.

So, if you **register** a `broadcastReceiver` in `onCreate()` then you will have to **unregister** it in `onDestroy()` so that this registered `broadcastReceiver` does not affect to other `Activity` after the destruction of this `Activity`.

> 2 - If you register a receiver in onResume(), you should unregister it
>   in onPause() to prevent registering it multiple times

`onResume()` is called whenever this `Activity` is **active** and **visible** and onPause() is called whenever this `Activity` is **invisible** or **inactive**.

So, if you **register** a `broadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` then this is called whenever `Activity` is **visible** and **active**, so it will be registered multiple times in **one lifecycle** of an `Activity`, so you will have to call `unregisterReceiver` in `onPause()`, this will **unregister** the registered receiver whenever you `Activity` is **invisible** and **inactive**.

Comment: After `onPause`, the activity may be partially covered, but still visible

Comment: Not fully visible and active

Comment: What if i want to listen an SMS message notificaiton, Do my activity must be on resume state?

Comment: If you're doing an SMS app, you would register the receiver in the manifest. If it's only to automatically fill a confirmation code, it's better to do on resumed state (because it's the same case as the user typing the code)

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir True, but **not fully visible** is different from **invisible**, which is in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You should unregister the receiver in the corresponding event of the one where you register it. This will prevent registering/unregistering in an unbalanced way.

For instance, let's say you registered it in `onCreate`, but you're unregistering in `onPause`. Your activity is created and registers the receiver. Then you show a dialog. `onPause` is called and you unregister the receiver. Now the dialog is dismissed. `onResume` is called and your activity continues. But it's not recreated, `onCreate` won't be called and your the receiver was already unregistered, you won't get broadcasts anymore in this activity.

That's why it's important to use the correct pair of lifecycle events.

And a little explanation of those events you mentioned:
`onCreate` happens when the `Activity` is created and `onResume` when it **goes into foreground**. The corresponding closing events are `onPause` when it **leaves the foreground**, e.g., a dialog covers the `Activity` partially or the user navigates away from the `Activity`, with another one covering it fully (in that case, `onStop` would also be called). If the `Activity` is destroyed due to a configuration change (e.g., rotation) or the system reclaiming it, `onDestroy` is called.

A little digression here: specifically about `onCreate`/`onDestroy`, I would avoid that pair for broadcast receiver registration. The reason is that `onDestroy` may take too long to be called or may never be called (as per Android specification, it's not guaranteed, the activity's memory may be collected without calling `onDestroy`). Another example: your activity is created, you register the receiver. Then you navigate from that activity to another. It receives `onPause` and then `onStop`, you're in another activity, but the previous one is still listening to broadcasts.

Comment: Thank you @Douglas Drumond. That is what i want.